# Obtener la fila de un table html con framework datatable para C#

Tags: html, c#, .net

Amigos Tengo un problema al obtener la fila de una table el cual me obliga a crear webform y no usar modal el cual intetente obtener
 `<a href="EditarEmpleado.aspx?identidad=<%=txtidentidad.value= getRegistros() ["identidad"].ToString() %>`  y trae el modal el problema que me esta traendo la ultima fila y quiero obtener de acuerdo a la que selecciono, su ayuda trabajo con c# el problema que solo asi pude llenar la tabla y por cuestion de diseño con el gridview debo de trabajar con el modelo de la table y el framework de datatables , mil gracias de antemano.

```
    <table id="Table" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Identidad</th>
          <th>Nombres</th>
          <th>Apellidos</th>
          <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
          <th>Correo</th>
          <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
          <th>Salario</th>
          <th>Id_Profit</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <%
        while (getRegistros().Read())
        {
          %>
          <tr>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["identidad"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["nom_empleado"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["ape_empleado"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["fech_nacimiento"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["correo_electronico"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["fech_ingreso"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["salario"]%></td>
            <td><% =getRegistros() ["id_profit"]%></td>
            <td > 

              <a href="EditarEmpleado.aspx?identidad=<%= getRegistros() ["identidad"].ToString() %>&nombres=<% =getRegistros() ["nom_empleado"].ToString() %>&apellidos=<%=  getRegistros() ["ape_empleado"].ToString() %>&Fechanacimiento=<%= getRegistros() ["fech_nacimiento"].ToString() %>
                &correo=<% =getRegistros() ["correo_electronico"].ToString() %>&fechaingreso=<% =getRegistros() ["fech_ingreso"].ToString() %>&salario=<% =getRegistros() ["salario"].ToString() %>&idprofit=<% =getRegistros() ["id_profit"].ToString() %>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> 

                <%--<a href="../MaestraPrincipal.Master">../MaestraPrincipal.Master</a>f="Principal.aspx?id=<%=getRegistros() ["id"].ToString() %>&nombre=<%=getRegistros() ["nombre"].ToString() %>&nombre=<%=getRegistros() ["edad"].ToString() %>" ><i class="fas fa-edit" onserverclick="EditarTable" id="EditarTable" runat="server"></i></a> --%>
                &nbsp &nbsp
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"   onclick="eliminar('Eliminar.aspx?identidad=<%= getRegistros() ["identidad"].ToString() %>')" style="" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" ></i></a>
              </td> 
            </tr>
            <%
          }
          %>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Identidad</th>
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
            <th>Salario</th>
            <th>Id_Profit</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>

          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

Para Leandro Tuntini

```
 Variables

private Empleados emp;
 private SqlDataReader registro;
```

en load

```
this.emp = new Empleados();
        registro = this.emp.getempleado();
```

'funcion

```
  public SqlDataReader getRegistros()
    {

        return this.registro;
    }
```

'clase de conexion

```
public class Conexion
{


private SqlConnection conexion;
public Conexion()
{
    string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RRHHBD"].ConnectionString;
    this.conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
}
public void conectar()
{
    this.conexion.Open();
}
public void cerrar()
{
    this.conexion.Close();
}
public SqlConnection getConexion()
{
    return this.conexion;
}



 }
```

'Clase de empleados

```
public class Empleados : Conexion
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlDataReader Registro;


    public Empleados()
    {
        this.con = getConexion();
    }

    public SqlDataReader getempleado()
    {
        conectar();
        string sql = "SELECT  [identidad],[nom_empleado],[ape_empleado],[fech_nacimiento],[correo_electronico],[fech_ingreso],[salario],[id_profit] FROM[TXRRHH].[dbo].[empleados] ";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, this.con);
        this.Registro = comando.ExecuteReader();


        return this.Registro;
    }
```

}

Comment: es una aplicacion `asp.net` es un aspx? que es getRegistros() ? porque pueste el tag ajax y jquery per no veo nada de eso, tampoco hay nada javascript

Comment: si es en apsx y getregistro es un datareader (que me llena la tabla ) ya que fue la unica forma que pude llenar y se que se puede con repeater pero no me da la opcion del framework  osea que descarto esa opcion, y puse javascript o ajax porque creo que se podria obtener con alguna funcion y mil disculpas por poner esas opciones

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo con la misma tecnica, deberias recuperar solo una vez el `reader` y usarlo dentro del `while`

Algo como esto

```
<%
var reader = getRegistros();
while (reader.Read()){%>
  <tr>
    <td><% =reader["identidad"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["nom_empleado"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["ape_empleado"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["fech_nacimiento"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["correo_electronico"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["fech_ingreso"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["salario"]%></td>
    <td><% =reader["id_profit"]%></td>
    <td > 

      <a href="EditarEmpleado.aspx?identidad=<%= reader["identidad"].ToString() %>&nombres=<% =reader["nom_empleado"].ToString() %>&apellidos=<%=  reader["ape_empleado"].ToString() %>&Fechanacimiento=<%= reader["fech_nacimiento"].ToString() %>
        &correo=<% =reader["correo_electronico"].ToString() %>&fechaingreso=<% =reader["fech_ingreso"].ToString() %>&salario=<% =reader["salario"].ToString() %>&idprofit=<% =reader["id_profit"].ToString() %>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> 

        <%--<a href="../MaestraPrincipal.Master">../MaestraPrincipal.Master</a>f="Principal.aspx?id=<%=reader["id"].ToString() %>&nombre=<%=reader["nombre"].ToString() %>&nombre=<%=reader["edad"].ToString() %>" ><i class="fas fa-edit" onserverclick="EditarTable" id="EditarTable" runat="server"></i></a> --%>
        &nbsp &nbsp
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"   onclick="eliminar('Eliminar.aspx?identidad=<%= reader["identidad"].ToString() %>')" style="" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" ></i></a>
      </td> 
    </tr>
<%}%>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Amigo Leandro hice la prueba y no me funciona cuando realice 
 la prueba mandando asi el dato (   href="exampleModal?identidad=<%= txtprueba.value= reader["identidad"].ToString() %>   ), vuelvo a tener el mismo problema con obtener solo la ultima fila no se si lo hago por codebehind , cabe resaltar que si lo mando a otra pagina no tengo problema, en realidad el problema es mantenerlo en la misma pagina para asi hacer modales , gracias por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo de getRegistros()

Comment: la edite con la conexion y las funciones , si hay alguna otra forma de trabajar la table de html como si fuera un gridview seria bueno , si sabe alguna otra alternativa de llenar la table (que no sea con repeater ya que con este tuve problemas) y manejar las filas  seria perfecto , de igual forma intente con datatable pero no tuve exito  y por eso estoy con el datareader.

Comment: Una recomendacion, no te animas a retornar un `DataTable` como respuesta, iterando por medio de `foreach(var row in dt.Rows)` creo que ests teniendo problemas por el ida y vuelta que haces con un objeto que en reaidad es un cursor a la db, si trabjas con un objeto desconectado podria resolverse